# Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected kotlin

Tags: android, string, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors

I got error message:

```
AddAddressActivity.kt: (69, 53): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Please paste edit your question and paste the actual text.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `getString` method returns a nullable value (`String?`) but you are assigning it to something that takes a non-null value (expects `String`). If you want to fix it you could assign it to a default string if it is null like this

```kotlin
val villageId = getString("village_id") ?: "default"
```

or to an empty string

```kotlin
val villageId = getString("village_id").orEmpty()
```

Comment: Or use the standard library function `.orEmpty()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your `villageId` can be null which you have got from `getString("village_id")`

for solving this you can use default value so when bundle don't contains the provided key it will eventually returns the default value.

```
val villageId = getString("village_id", "My Default Value")
```

or you can use kotlin elvis to get other value when it's null.

```
val villageId = getString("village_id") ?: "My Default Value"
```

or if you're sure that intent will always contain the village id then you can use !!(not-null assertion operator) which will convert non-null value if not null else will throw exception

```
val villageId: String = getString("village_id")!!
```

you can more read about null safety in following link [Null safety | Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator)